# Add custom response header to web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-6, asp.net-2.0

I have a website that is susceptible to a clickjacking vulnerability. Doing some research, it looks like one of the simple approaches is to simply add the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` to the response header. This is a very old web application (ca. last update was 2004), and is running IIS 6 with ASP.NET 2.0.

In newer versions, I could simply add the following section to the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And that would be the end of it. However, I can't seem to be able to verify that this is possible using IIS 6.

Is this possible with IIS 6 and ASP.NET 2.0 to be done in only the `web.config` file? If so, how? If not, what code changes would I have to make in order to achieve the same result? Would simply adding

```
Context.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

to the `Global.asax#Application_EndRequest` be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you'll be able to accomplish this solely by updating the `web.config` since you are targeting II6 (as support for the `<customHeaders>` section was added in IIS7+).

What you would likely need to do would be to create a custom HttpModule similar to the approach mentioned in [this blog post](http://sudhanshutheone.net/2013/10/14/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https/) that would handle actually adding the Header which might look something like this :

```
public class SameOriginHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
     private HttpApplication _application;

     public void Init(HttpApplication context)
     {
         _application = context;
         context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
     }

     void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // If your request exists, add the header
         if (_application.Context != null)
         {
              var response = _application.Response;
              response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
         }
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {

     }
 }
```

You would then need to register this module within your `web.config` file as seen below :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="SameOriginHeaderModule" type="SameOriginHeaderModule" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use a custom module instead of my second approach of adding it to the Global.asax file? I like the custom module idea, just curious if there's a reason to use one over the other.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noticed that snippet of code. Yes, that should be sufficient as well, although you may want to target the [`Application_PreSendRequestHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders(v=vs.110).aspx) event if possible as it might be a better time to add the headers.